# Java - JComponent in polygon shape with background image

Tags: java, jframe, jcomponent

I want to have a JComponent on my JFrame, that has a custom shape in form of a polygon. Now i want to add a background image with colors in the same shape and blank color in the rest.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I have this test class:

```
public class Test extends JButton {
private final Polygon shape;
private final int provinceId;
private ImageIcon img;

public Test(Polygon p, int x, int y, int w, int h, int id, ImageIcon img) {
    this.shape = p;
    this.provinceId = id;
    this.img = img;
    setSize(w, h);
    setLocation(x, y);
    setIcon(img);
    setContentAreaFilled(false);
    addMouseListener(animation());
}

private MouseListener animation() {
    return new MouseListener() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("in");
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("out");
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    };
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawPolygon(this.shape);
}

protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
    g.drawPolygon(this.shape);
}

public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
    return this.shape.contains(x, y);
}

public boolean isOpaque() {
    return false;
}

public int getId() {
    return this.provinceId;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    //Polygon p = new Polygon(new int[] {0, 400, 400, 0}, new int[] {0, 0, 300, 300}, 4);
    Polygon p = new Polygon(new int[] {50, 150, 250, 350, 200, 50}, new int[] {0, 0, 50, 200, 300, 200}, 6);
    ImageIcon ico = new ImageIcon("gfx/test.png");
    Test t = new Test(p, 20, 20, 400, 300, 101, ico);
    f.getContentPane().add(t);
    f.setSize(500, 400);
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

but i only get this output: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFxIR.png)

My original picture was: [wanted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn2f5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by overriding the `contains(Point p)` method to only return true when `p` is in the bounds of your custom shape.

Then you best override `isOpaque()` to return false.

And finally you override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` to paint your component in whatever way you like (e.g. a background image with colors in the shape and blank color in the rest).

Sample code:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel()
{
    @Override
    public boolean isOpaque()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Point p)
    {
        // Use something that fits your shape here.
        return p.getX() % 2 == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        // do some painting
    }
};
```

Comment: a thing i should had added, is that i want to put some of these components next to each other. How is it, that the over-reaching corneres arent blocking each other.

Comment: You will have to place your components overlapping each other making sure your contains method takes care of determining which of your components are hit.

Comment: This means using a layout that allows you to overlap your components.

Comment: I have updated my question with the attempts ive made. Could you please take a look and maybe even say me what im doing wrong?

Comment: It seems to work? As soon as I enter the polygon with my mouse it says `in` and when I move the mouse out again it says `out`

Comment: In order to change the way your polygon draws you need to change your `paintComponent`. For example use `fillPolygon` instead of `drawPolygon`. Or change your graphics context color. But you probably want to read up on a tutorial for that :)

Comment: e.g. look here: http://www.bogotobogo.com/Java/tutorials/javagraphics3.php

Comment: The `in` and the `out` where just for testing. I want the second picture inside the polygons bounds. That is the main question.

Comment: Ah I see your problem. I should have mentioned. You need to change the clipping area of your `Graphics` in the `paintComponent` method using `g.setClip(this.shape)` and then call `super.paintComponent(g)`.

Comment: Thats was what i needed. Im glad this place has such nice members and i thank you for your time spent :)

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help.